# Execute simple select query using Rocket U2 Toolkit for .NET

Tags: .net, u2, unidata, u2netdk, rocket-u2

Executing the following code fails on command.ExecuteReader() with exception:

"ERROR [] [U2] [UCINET-UO] ERROR [] [U2] [UCINET-UO]  [U2][UCINET-UO]  [U2][UCINET-UO] XTOOLSUB Subroutine failed. Log to Account (2). Invalid account name /data/TSSA9. Make sure /data/TSSA account is listed in ud_database file and UD.ACCOUNT.  Class Name = UDAttribute Method Name = GetAttributes(...) Class Name = UDAttribute Method Name = GetAttributes(...) Source:U2.Data.Client TargetSite:U2.Data.Client.NativeAccess.TableInfoForNativeAccess GetTableInformation(U2.Data.Client.U2Command)"

```
using (var connection = ConnectionFactory.Create())
using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandText = "Select ID From CONTRACTORS;";
    connection.Open();
    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            var o = reader[0];
        }
    }
}

public class ConnectionFactory
{
    public const string Password = "****";
    public const string UserName = "****";
    public const string Server = "****";

    public static U2Connection Create()
    {
        var connectionStringBuilder = new U2ConnectionStringBuilder
        {
            UserID = UserName,
            Password = Password,
            Server = Server,
            Database = "/data/TSSA",
            ServerType = "UNIDATA",
            AccessMode = "Native", // FOR UO
            RpcServiceType = "udcs", // FOR UO
            Connect_Timeout = 9000,
            QueryTimeout = 9000,
            PersistSecurityInfo = true,
            Pooling = false
        };

        return new U2Connection
        {
            ConnectionString = connectionStringBuilder.ToString()
        };
    }
}
```

I'm using U2.Data.Client version 2.1.0.2051

Any thoughts or ideas would be very appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you confirmed that account /data/TSSA is indeed in the ud_database file and UD.ACCOUNT?

Comment: Well that's a great question. Unfortunately I'm not sure what that means or how to check or what to do if it isn't. I was under the impression that connecting this way meant I didn't need to update server configs but apparently I'm wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for asking this question.
Make sure database ‘/data/TSAA’ is listed in two places.

1. ud_database (see screen shot) (in windows, C:\U2\ud73\INCLUDE\ud_database)
2. UD.ACCOUNT (see screen shot)
   a.  Logto ‘sys’ account
   b.  LIST UD.ACCOUNT
   c.  Make sure you have ‘/data/TSAA’ entry there.

We will fix this issue in V 2.2.0 so that you do not need to do the above said  extra steps.

This issue is resolved in U2 Toolkit for .NET v2.2.0 (BETA). Read this for more information.

[Async\Await and Entity Framework  6.1 in Rocket MV U2 Toolkit for .NET v2.2.0 (BETA)](http://www.rsusers.org/cms/pages/messages.wsp)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are these files on the server or the client? Our db server is a unix box.

Comment: When I log into udt and execute the LIST UD.ACCOUNT command I get "Not a filename". Sorry but my unidata knowledge is rather sparse.

Comment: you need to do, LOGTO sys. See another answer for details.

Comment: I don't seem to have permission since I receive a errno=13: Permission denied

Comment: Could you please send us email u2askus@rocketsoftware.com (Attn: Rajan Kumar)? We will try to provide you a tool that updates your UD. ACCOUNT’ file.
In the meantime , you can try ‘demo’ account. So you need to replace ‘‘/data/TSAA’ with ‘demo’. I hope ‘demo’ account is listed both in ‘ud_database’ and ‘UD.ACCOUNT’.

Comment: I've requested that I'd be given access so hopefully soon I'll get it. I'll send you an email shortly. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Type in the following commands at the ":" prompt

LOGTO sys
LIST UD.ACCOUNT ALL

You may see a list like this:

[image]